# how to find zip and php files on a website ? ( phishing kit extractor)

Tags: python

im trying to make a script that will get all websites from openfish.com and extract zip and php files in the url so i can download the phishing kit and analyze it manually. Any idea how i can scan a website for zip or php  files ? maybe i should use a wordlist and brute force the url ? I tried the below but it doesnt seem to be working

```
url = 'https://sec-livri-fy.net/scms/index.php'
ext = 'php'

    def listFD(url, ext=''):
        page = requests.get(url).text
    
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
        return [url + '/' + node.get('href') for node in soup.find_all('a') if node.get('href').endswith(ext)]
    
    for file in listFD(url, ext):
        print (file)
```

Comment: `soup.find_all('a', href=True)` could help

Comment: this will just get me all the links on the website , i need to get zip and php files ...

Comment: no, with that you are sure that all `a` tags will have a `href` attribute which could be not always the case

Comment: `soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile(r'php|zip$'))` need the `re` module for regex

Comment: https://academyselfdefense.com/ tried it on this website , it doesnt find wp-login.php page

Comment: ...bs4 deals with static webpages not with dynamic ones

Comment: wrong tools... or wrong "requests"

Comment: its a static website , the php login page is always there

Comment: it is the javascript code... try to use your browser, click view source, copy-paste it into a file then run the code